# Iterating over array elements with gnu parallel

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel, bash-array

I have an input file, *names.txt*, with the 1 word per line:

```
apple  
abble  
aplle
```

With my bash script I am trying to achieve the following output:

```
apple and apple  
apple and abble  
apple and aplle  
abble and apple  
abble and abble  
abble and aplle  
aplle and apple  
aplle and abble  
aplle and aplle
```

Here is my bash script

```
#!/usr/bin bash
readarray -t seqcol < names.txt

joiner () {
           val1=$1
           val2=$2
           echo "$val1 and $val2"
}

export -f joiner

parallel -j 20 '
    line=($(echo {}))
    for word in "${line[@]}"; do
            joiner "${line}" "${word}"
    done
' ::: "${seqcol[@]}"
```

but it is only outputting the following 3 lines comparing identical elements from the array

```
apple and apple  
abble and abble  
aplle and aplle
```

I have the script that uses `while read line` loop, but it is too slow (my actual datafile is has about 200k lines). That is why I want to use array elements and `gnu parallel` at the same to speed the process up.
I have tried different ways of accessing the array elements within the `parallel ' '` command (by mainly modifying this loop - `for word in "${line[@]}"`, or by supplying the array to `parallel` via `printf '%s\n' "${seqcol[@]}"`) but they are either leading to errors or output blank lines.

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU Parallel can generate all combinations of input sources.

In your case you simply use `names.txt` twice:

```
parallel -k echo {1} and {2} :::: names.txt names.txt
```

Or (if you really have an array):

```
readarray -t seqcol < names.txt
parallel -kj 20 echo {1} and {2} ::: "${seqcol[@]}" ::: "${seqcol[@]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

`parallel` won't necessarily keep the right order of output.

Anyways, if you care about performance, don't use `bash` to work with text files. Instead use a dedicated tool, like `awk` or a programming language, e.g. `python`.

```bash
awk '
  { words[NR]=$0 }
  END {
    for (x in words){
      for (y in words) { printf "%s and %s\n",words[x],words[y] }
    }
  }' file
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, @pLumo!
The awk solution is much neater, but can I still pass a function into awk and will it be faster than gnu parallel or xargs alternatives? (As sometimes there is more than 1 function and they are more complex than just printing 2 strings with "and" in between)

Comment: @duda13 the shell will almost always be the slowest option for this, so yes, you should avoid it whenever you can. Awk is a full programming language, so you can do anything you want to do, but no you can't export bash functions into awk, you would have to write an awk function instead.

Comment: I am aware that shell is not the best solution, but I cannot use python or R in this case. And I am not that familiar with awk scripting, especially in the context of complex functions. I have functions in bash that work well, but I just need to parallelize the script to make them faster.